# Point-Slope Equation of a line. Why is one answer incorrect and other is correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reviewing basic algebra.

I am using quiz from [this](http://www.mathopolis.com/questions/q.php?id=519&site=1&ref=/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html&qs=519_521_522_1160_1161_1162_2074_2075_9027_9028_9029) link, and I solved the equation on paper and I get answer which is showing incorrect, I do not understand why is it wrong?

It says my answer is correct but not for point-slope, can someone explain why?

Here are the question and the correct answer:

[image]

Comment: If you show your answer, we could look at what is wrong.

Comment: Please see the image link I posted. I selected A and answer is C.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. A is correct too, but they say it's wrong because it's not in "point-slope" form, which I have never heard of before.

Comment: Point slope form is $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, where any point on the line, say $(x_1, y_1)$ and the slope $m$ are both explicit. I wouldn't worry too much either.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the equation of the line passing through $(x_1, y_1)$ & having slope $m$ is given as  $$\color{red}{y-y_1=m(x-x_1)}$$
From the diagram $$\text{slope of line}, m=\frac{\text{perpendicular}}{\text{base}}=\frac{3}{1}=3$$

Hence, the equation of the line passing through $(1, 2)$ & having $\text{slope}=3$  is given as $$\color{blue}{y-2=3(x-1)}$$
It is clear that the options (A) & (C) are representing same line if simplified but the form of point & slope is incorrectly represented by option (A). Hence, $\color{blue}{(C)}$ hence both are correct

Comment: I am just concerned about that the test will be multiple choice so it may count A as incorrect answer.

Comment: Yes, the option must be appropriate one . Hence only option (C) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So the point you are given is $(x, y)=(1,2)$. The line passes through the point $y=-1$ when $x=0$. If you 'count' $2$ units to the right from this point on the y-axis and then $6$ units up you will then see that the gradient of the line is $$\frac{y-2}{x-1}=\frac{6}{2}$$
Hence the equation of the line is
$$y-2=3(x-1)$$